# Inject method restful service

Tags: java, rest, inject

I have a bunch of RESTful web services(80) with `@GET` and `@PUT` methods. I want to add an `@OPTIONS` method to each service. Instead of manualy writing `@OPTIONS` method for each service I want to be able to inject them in the services. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exaclty your environment, but i think the best way in technologies I use is to specify the "auto-scan" property in the configuration file, the declaration of this property differs a little from a technology to another one, but the idea remain the same : all componants are scanned at the beginning of deploiment
sorry for my english :) but i hope this response helps you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I'm using eclipse, and I have no Idea how to do what you just said. can you help me more

Comment: It differs depending on what you are using as technology, for example in a spring environment, you have just to add in the application-config.xml a line whith indicate to spring the package containing your annotated classes, methodes and attributes; 
<context:component-scan base-package="org.yourNs.pack" />